# Unable to access Selenium Standalone server (Started on Azure) using Public IP

Tags: python, azure, selenium, selenium-grid

I am trying to host selenium standalone server on Azure Virtual Machine (Windows server - 2019).

I followed the documentation and started the server using:

```
java -jar ss.jar -host 127.0.0.1 -port 5555
```

After that referring to https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12833/how-to-connect-node-to-hub-that-are-in-different-networks, I added inbound and outbound rules in firewall on Azure.

For allowing all the traffic.

Still, I am not able to access the server using the public IP address on my local machine:

> http://<public_ip>:5555/

Any help or support will be really helpful.

Comment: I have a feeling that binding that process to localhost is not ideal, `127.0.0.1` is typically not exposed to any of the network interfaces

Comment: Can you tell me how I can check that? @C.Nivs
Your any help would be really helpful for me.